# TopCased: API to Export a SysML Diagram

Tags: eclipse, mda, sysml

I need to export a number of TopCased SysML (Eclipse) diagrams into png/jpg programmatically? Is there any API allowing this ?

Comment: I don't know if the topcased team looks at stackoverflow ... and this question does not concern "Acceleo". If you get no answer here, you will have better luck on http://lists.gforge.enseeiht.fr/mailman/listinfo/topcased-users.